# How to create docker images for Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric

I made changes to fabric code and would like to test it by running using docker-compose. I run `make peer; make docker`. I see the following.

```
mkdir -p build/image/peer/payload
cp build/docker/bin/peer build/sampleconfig.tar.bz2 build/image/peer/payload
mkdir -p build/image/orderer/payload
cp build/docker/bin/orderer build/sampleconfig.tar.bz2 build/image/orderer/payload
mkdir -p build/image/testenv/payload
cp build/docker/bin/orderer build/docker/bin/peer build/sampleconfig.tar.bz2 images/testenv/install-softhsm2.sh build/image/testenv/payload
mkdir -p build/image/tools/payload
cp build/docker/bin/cryptogen build/docker/bin/configtxgen build/docker/bin/configtxlator build/docker/bin/peer build/sampleconfig.tar.bz2 build/image/tools/payload
```

When I do `docker images`, I still see the same bunch of images

```
hyperledger/fabric-orderer    latest    391b202306fa    3 weeks ago 180MB
hyperledger/fabric-orderer    x86_64-1.1.0 391b202306fa 3 weeks ago 180MB
hyperledger/fabric-peer       latest    e0f3bdb4506f    3 weeks ago 187MB
hyperledger/fabric-peer       x86_64-1.1.0 e0f3bdb4506f 3 weeks ago 187MB
```

How do I go from there to generate new docker image? what am I missing?

I am using Ubuntu 16.04. Thanks for your time

Comment: you may need to run make clean before trying to build the images

Answer (score 1):

```
cd build/image/peer/
docker build -t hyperledger/fabric-peer:x86_64-1.1.x .
```

Change the image name in docker-compose.yaml file and you are good to go.